# Recursively find ONLY the latest logs in all sub-folders and save to file

Tags: awk, sed, grep, find

I am working on a RHEL7 box.  I need to recursively find all the LATEST (and only the latest) .log  files in each sub-folder below a certain hierarchy and list their full paths in a file 'all_logs.txt'.

My find command looks like this and works to return full paths to ~6000 records:

```
cd ${SEARCHDIR}
find . -iname computer_import_*.log > all_logs.txt
```

The problem here is that this find command is finding ALL computer_import_*.log where I just need the latest computer_import_*.log file in each sub-folder searched.

Answer (score 0):

```
find ${SEARCHDIR} -type f -iname "computer_import_*.log" -mtime -10 > all_logs.txt
```

This will find all files that match the `-iname` argument, restricted to being modified within 10-days of the run.  See the `find` manpages for more details.

Note that the `-iname` argument is quoted so that `find` interprets the argument rather than the shell before `find` runs.

If you want to see what's returned based on these criteria do, for example:

```
find ${SEARCHDIR} -type f -iname "computer_import_*.log" -mtime -10 -exec ls -ld {} +
```

This will perform an `ls` on each file returned, thus showing the last modification date.  Change the value of `-mtime <+-N>` to your taste.  A value of `-90` would return files modified in the last 90 days.  A positive value of `+90` would return files modified over 90 days ago.

** ALTERNATIVE INTERPRETATION **

Given the requirement to find *only* the most recent file in *any* and *all* sub-directories, do something like this:

```
find ${SEARCHDIR} -type d > /var/tmp/mydirs
while read -r line
do
    ls -alt "${line}" | grep -Ev "^(d|total)" | head -1 >> /var/tmp/mylogs
done < /var/tmp/mydirs
```

The `ls` orders the contents of a directory as newest to oldest modification date. The `grep` eliminates directory entries and total size lines.  `head` snips the first file (if any) from the directory being examined.

Comment: Thx, but this wont work because I could have the latest log be 3mo old or more.

Comment: All I appreciate all the feedback but still no luck.  It is sounding to me that there is no real good way to search sub-dirs. and extract ONLY the SINGE absolute latest log file in said directory.  None of these answers do that.  Thx.

Comment: See the alternative interpretation update.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with below command  and it worked fine

```
find . -type f -iname "computer_import_*.log" -daystart -mtime -1 > all_logs.txt
```

Comment: I should have been more clear sorry... it does work and returns ~70 records and they all look like the latest.  The problem is there should be ~400 records returned by the command.  My speculation is that this is because I could easily have the latest record be from last year.  Perhaps its working for you because you don't have records that old?  Thx very new at this!

Comment: Will check and update